# Cuda issue in TensorFlow 1.0 tutorial looks like TF can't find CUPTI/lib64?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

This question has nothing to do with the warnings SSE AVX etc.. I've included the output for completeness. The issue is the fail on some cuda libs, I think, at the end, the machine has a NVIDA 1070 card and has the Cuda libs that are used earlier in the process but something is missing at the end?
I pip installed release 1.0 of TensorFlow
I also downloaded the repo separately to get the most up to date tutorials.
This tutorial specifically to get instances of all of Tensorboard capabilities..
Attempting to run the Minst_with_summaries.py from the tensorFlow tutorials in the repo (I copied the file out of the repo into a working directory) and I'm using Anaconda and Python 3.6 I get the following:

```
(py36) tom@tomServal:~/Documents/LearningRepos/Working$ python Minst_with_summaries.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.645
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.48GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
Accuracy at step 0: 0.1213
Accuracy at step 10: 0.6962
Accuracy at step 20: 0.8054
Accuracy at step 30: 0.8447
Accuracy at step 40: 0.8718
Accuracy at step 50: 0.8779
Accuracy at step 60: 0.8846
Accuracy at step 70: 0.8783
Accuracy at step 80: 0.8853
Accuracy at step 90: 0.8989
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcupti.so.8.0. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/usr/local/cuda/lib64
F tensorflow/core/platform/default/gpu/cupti_wrapper.cc:59] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (::tensorflow::Env::Default()->GetSymbolFromLibrary( GetDsoHandle(), kName, &f)) (OK vs. Not found: /home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: cuptiActivityRegisterCallbacks)could not find cuptiActivityRegisterCallbacksin libcupti DSO
Aborted
```

Looks to me that the installation of TensorFlow may be missing some stuff See that last several lines above?
How to fix? 
Also reference this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7975

The answer was posted on GitHub and it seems there is an install bug that can be fixed by:

```
adding /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Would be helpful if @mrry would reopen so others can see the correct resolution.

Comment: As edited and noted, nothing to do with the warnings...

Comment: Answer added in Body since question incorrectly closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also reference this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7975

You may try the apt-get install that the git-hub issue suggests but that did not do it for me: This did:

The answer was posted on GitHub and it seems there is an install bug that can be fixed by:

```
adding /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

you can do that by editing your .bash profile

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this on my windows. I solved by add `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64` to environment variables.